# Two WHERE condition in mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I had an error in my website that says

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in ../../../guestbook.php on line 117
```

When I check my line 117

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
```

And I think my query is wrong...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE permission='0' AND ignore='0' ORDER BY gbid DESC");
```

I think I always get an error when I use the word AND and I don't know how to make TWO WHERE conditions.

If I'm lack of description or codes needed to solve this, please do ask so that I can edit it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: The syntax looks fine.  Check `mysql_error()`.  Also, if permission and ignore are numeric fields, you should use ` = 0` instead of ` = '0'`.

Comment: Try your query in phpMyAdmin. Perhaps you mispelled the field name or something. Also it will show you useful error message.

Comment: @bsdnoobz You don't need phpmyadmin to see error messages. That would be a lot of effort to debug one query if he doesn't already have it installed.

Comment: After I've check it with mysql_error() it says, Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ignore=0 ORDER BY gbid DESC' . . . I've check my tables and rows and all of them are correct.

Comment: Try stripping the SQL back to bare bones and adding a condition one at a time so you see which one breaks it.  Given some of the answers, I would remove the ignore= first.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to check if the query is wrong:

```
$result = mysql_query(... your query here ...) or die(mysql_error());
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Simply have mysql TELL you if something's wrong. Your error message means the query has failed for some reason, you blindly assumed it succeeded, and tried to use the boolean FALSE value that mysql_query returned in subsequent operations. Never assume a DB operation has succeeded.

---

edit: given your error message, it's because `ignore` is a reserved word. Escape it with backticks:

```
... AND `ignore`=0 ORDER BY ...
        ^      ^
```

to force mysql to treat it as a fieldname instead.

Comment: After I've check it with mysql_error() it says, Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ignore=0 ORDER BY gbid DESC' . . . I've check my tables and rows and all of them are correct.

Comment: `ignore` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql. you'll have to escape it with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

ignore is reserved word in mysql. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

You can simply try

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE `permission`= 0 AND `ignore`=0 ORDER BY gbid DESC");
```

or change coloum name

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook WHERE permission= 0 AND ignore=0 ORDER BY gbid DESC");
```

If permission and ignore are TYPE INT, then no quotes is required...

Comment: Even if the fields are integral types, if the statement the user posted will error, so will this one.

Comment: MySQL will auto-convert as appropriate, so this is a pointless change.